# packages reuse when upgrading Ubuntu 12.04 to Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, upgrade

I have two machines that are both with `Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit`. Now I've upgraded one into the `Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit`. And I want to upgrade the other into 14.04. Is it possible to copy directly the downloaded packages into the other machine to less the upgrading process?

Another question is, should I recompile the softwares(e.g. boost, mpich2, and so on) that have compiled with `12.04 64bit` when the system is upgraded into `14.04`? And should I re-install those softwares?  Is there any problems of compatibility?

Comment: Should probably be two separate questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to copy directly the downloaded packages into the other machine to less the upgrading process?

You can in theory copy the *.deb files from `/var/cache/apt/archives/` from one computer to the other, as that is the cache for downloaded packages.  Then it should be able to install the matching packages on the other PC without re-downloading, as long as they are the same version and same architecture.

The only reason this may not be possible is if for some reason this cache has been purged already (eg with the likes of `apt-get clean`).